# how to clerar items in TTS Queue (Android)

Tags: android

My Use case is like "Pressing on the skip button should clear the current item from the TTS and start from the next".

Is there any way to clear or flush the item which I had already added to TTS.

Please do help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just call tts.stop() the queue will be flushed

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a valid TTS engine, created as follow:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
```

If you do

```
tts.speak("sentence", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

that will flush the TTS queue and say `sentence` straight away.